# Is there any simple example for login screen using Riverpod Flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

I am new to state management in flutter. I am learning it though, Can anyone please let me know the code structure of state management using riverpod in flutter with simple example.

Thank you

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the web for state management in Flutter(also for Riverpod). I wrote an article on using the Provider package (which might help you out). You can check it out [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-state-of-the-flutter-4a178325cced).